# Formula relating attenuation and loss tangent in EM wave propagation?

Tags: electromagnetism, wave

in [this previously answered question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350709/relation-between-attenuation-and-loss-tangent-in-em-wave-propagation?newreg=4649a13393524165ba73b3c40f25b1ac), a relation is established between the attenuation and loss tangent in EM waves. The formula given is the following:

$$ \alpha = \frac{\omega}{c} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon'}{2}\cdot \left(\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \delta}-1\right)} $$

I have been trying to derive it from the complex propagation constant given by Balanis, but I arrive at a slightly different result (I think I might be mixing the nomenclature). Can you point to me where my error is? The following process is my mathematical development:

Starting with the equation from Balanis in "Advance engineering electromagnetics" (eq. 4-28c, pp 139)

$$ \alpha = \omega\sqrt{\varepsilon\mu} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left( \sqrt{1+\left( \frac{\sigma}{\omega\varepsilon} \right)^2}-1\right)} $$

I want to express the formula in terms of the losses, so:

$$ \tan\delta = \frac{\omega\varepsilon'' + \sigma}{\omega\varepsilon'} $$

I am assuming in the following that \$\varepsilon = \varepsilon' = \varepsilon_0 \varepsilon_r\$, that the relative magnetic permeability is 1, \$\mu_r = 1\$ and simplifying in terms of the speed of light in vacuum, \$c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon_0\mu_0}} \$:

$$ \alpha = \frac{\omega}{c} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon_r}{2}\cdot \left(\sqrt{1+\left( \frac{\sigma}{\omega\varepsilon} \right)^2}-1\right)} $$

What I am not sure now is how to work around the term that includes the conductivity. If I assume a non-ideal, lossless dielectric, then the \$\varepsilon'' = 0\$, and the final equation that I get is the following:

$$ \alpha = \frac{\omega}{c} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon_r}{2}\cdot \left(\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \delta}-1\right)}$$

Which is really close to the answer given in the aforementioned post, but differs in the permittivity term inside the square root, as

$$\epsilon' = \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r  \neq \varepsilon_r$$

Which equation is the correct one? Where is my error? Thanks in advance!